# What are the current options for storing, indexing, and querying geospatial data on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, geospatial

I've been 'away' from the GAE platform and community for a while, and recent new features look rather compelling, but I haven't been able to figure out what to do about geodata on GAE-Python. There are several open source libraries available:

1. [geomodel](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/)
2. [geodatastore](http://code.google.com/p/geodatastore/)
3. [mutiny](http://code.google.com/p/mutiny/)

...but they aren't being actively maintained and haven't been updated in quite a while, so I am left with several questions:

Do any of these libraries work with [NDB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/)? Is there something else I should try to use? What is the current best practice for geodata on GAE?

BTW, for my own project, I don't need to store anything other than points, and the sort of queries I need to make (at least initially) are 'X closest results to location Y' and 'all points within 1 mile of location Y'.

**UPDATED:** Based on comments, it looks like geomodel has been [patched](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/issues/detail?id=32#c3) to work with NDB, and it seems that the [new experimental Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Performing_Location-Based_Searches) allows for the kinds of searches I need. However, that leads to a new Q: Will the Search API simply obsolete geomodel and similar libraries, or will they still have a use?

Comment: GeoPtProperty of NDB and GeoPoint class of Search API would be a good start

Comment: See also [this](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/issues/detail?id=32) geomodel NDB patch

Comment: To UPDATE: The Search API is still experiment. Therefore, the amount of queries that you can perform is limited. Also, the pricing is yet to be determined. So, as of now, geomodel is a better alternative if you need to perform more queries then what is currently allowed, or you need to defined you total costs upfront.

Comment: Kyle, aside from the experimental nature of the Search API (quotas, uncertain costs), are there any _other_ reasons to use geomodel?

Answer (score 3):

To amplify one of the comments above -- the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview) now supports Geosearch.
It can retrieve results within a given radius and sort them by distance, so it should work well for what you want to do.

Comment: Amy, it isn't clear to me from your answer and the comments above whether the availability of Geosearch means that geomodel and similar libraries are no longer needed.

Comment: I'll have to look at those libraries in more detail before commenting further.  However, it does sound like the Search API's functionality is a good match for your particular use case.

Comment: Amy, have you actually gotten geosearch to work? no matter the parameters, I get 0 results on geosearch queries.